# String not properly initialized?

Tags: android, kotlin, jsoup

I am having a hard time making this app work. I can't seem to find relatable situation to serve as some kind of guide. Apparently *words* isn't recognized as a string resource and then my *Scrape* method is a "Unresolved reference"?

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val texx: TextView=findViewById(R.id.text1) as TextView
    val button:Button=findViewById(R.id.button1) as Button

    button.setOnClickListener(object : View.OnClickListener{
        override fun onClick(v: View) {
            Scrape().execute() //should work tho

        }
    })


    class Scrape() :AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

        lateinit var words: String

        override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Void?): Void? {

        try {
            val html = Jsoup.connect("https://www.wikipedia.com/en/Canada").get()
            words = html.text()

        }
        catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }

        return null
    }

        override fun onPostExecute(result: Void?) {
            super.onPostExecute(result)

            texx.text = getString(R.string.words)

        }
```

}

Comment: So like if you're trying to return `words` then why aren't you using the `RESULT` parameter in `AsyncTask`?

Comment: stop searching for views if you use kotlin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing it would be with a listener (not really elegant though):

- Define interface for listener in your Activity:

  ```
  interface WordsListener {
      fun onWordsReady(words: String)
  }
  ```
- Add it in `Scrape's` constructor:

  ```
  class Scrape(val wordsListener: WordsListener) : AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
  ```
- And pass it when creating `Scrape` in your `onCreate()`. Inside that listener, you can now access `texx` variable.

  ```
  Scrape(object: WordsListener {
      override fun onWordsReady(words: String) {
          texx.text = words
      }
  }).execute()
  ```

Another possibility would be to make `texx` a class variable, and mark `Scrape` as [inner class](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/nested-classes.html#inner-classes). This way, it would have access to `texx`. Remember though, that because inner classes carry a reference to an outer class, and can access outer class members, this can in some cases lead to memory leaks (eg. leaking your activity)

Some other improvements:

- you're not reading from `words` defined in `Scrape`, why have it? Do you want to use this, or `R.id.words`? This bit is confusing
- fix your indentation (indentation is very important for clarity when reading code)
- pay attention to variable names, eg. `texx`, `text1`, `button1` etc. are not the best names

Answer (score 0):

R.string.words would refer to a value inside of your strings.xml file. Try sending the value 'words' into the result parameter of asynctask

Comment: I managed to reframe it,  now words is  accessible because it is defined inside Scrape class, but I want to show result inside of TextView texx(defined in MainActivity) and I can't access it inside of onPostExecute